# error when try install new project in AdonisJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, installation, adonis.js

i got error when try install adonisJs using npm, my nodeJs version **v16.17.0**, and my npm version **9.6.1**

```
 Command failed with exit code 1: node ace configure tests Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) CREATE: test.ts CREATE: tests/bootstrap.ts CREATE: tests/functional/hello_world.spec.ts CREATE: contracts/tests.ts UPDATE: .adonisrc.json CREATE: .env.test UPDATE: tsconfig.json CREATE: .env.test [ wait ]  installing @japa/runner, @japa/preset-adonis ...

[ error ]  Unable to create project. Cleaning up
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade node version to v19.7.0, and it works for me!